# Silverstripes default homepage

Tags: php, silverstripe

I've searched all over the admin of Silverstripe version 3.2.1 and I can not find what makes my Home page (Menu(1)) the default homepage (/). How does Silverstripe decide which top level page to make the default homepage?

Answer (score 4):

Your home page is determined by the URL Segment. By default, the top-level page with a URL Segment named `home` will be your home page.

You can customize this via YAML config, by putting something like this in your `mysite/_config/config.yml` (or any config-file for that matter):

```
RootURLController:
  default_homepage_link: 'main'
```

The above config will make the page with URL segment `main` the home page.

Answer (score 1):

The default homepage is whichever pages url you set to '/home'.